# Non-interactive Zero-knowledge proof signature validation without public key

Tags: rsa, public-key, signature, zero-knowledge-proofs

I'm looking for a method for a scenario with following requirements:

At least 3 people (A,B,C,...) are in a Network where they can broadcast messages to everyone but not communicate with a specific person, so that they can't get answers to their broadcasts.

Every member has a public address "Apub, Bpub, .." (max ~100 bytes) which was derived from a private secret "Apriv, Bpriv, .."

- **A** signs a message with *Bpub* and broadcasts it to the network.
- **B** broadcasts a request (based on his *Bpriv/Bpub* without revealing these 2 keys) to validate, that the message from **A** belongs to him

Is **C** able to validate the request from **B**, without knowing *Bpriv/Bpub* and therefore not knowing his identity?

**A** shouldn't be able to proof, that the message was signed for himself without knowing *Bpriv*.

Are there existing code examples for this, which are free to use and free from patents?

Answer (score 2):

First, before I answer your questions: Money rewards are not forbidden, as far as I know, but that's not how it goes here. Feel free to check out the according [question on crypto-meta](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146/is-paying-or-donating-for-answers-allowed-here/).

I think, there are few conceptual misunderstandings in your scenario.

First, a signature scheme uses the private key (also called signing key) to sign messages, and it uses the public key (aka verification key) to verify, that a signature matches to a given message (under consideration of this verification key).

Then, you also want to use the public key as address set a limit of ~800 bit, which is a bad idea, because common schemes based on RSA or [Schnorr groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group) (like ElGamal signatures, DSA, etc.) are recommended to be larger (1240 bit at least).

And then, your scenario is quite weird, or maybe you used the wrong expressions. But if **A** broadcasts a message, he can not *sign* this message for **B** (signing requires the private key). If you meant "encrypt the message with the public key $B_{pub}$", it would make sense, but why would **B** send a request if this message was meant for him?And why would **C** not know the public key of **B**, if this was also used as address?

Maybe you should clarify your scenario, because right know I tend to the answer "no, it's not possible".

Comment: thanks for the answer. to clarify my scenario. it's about an e-coin system like bitcoin. i used the signing as a synonym here, not the actual signing that we know. what i want to achieve is, that A sends coins to B. but i have to make sure that only B can spend the coins. The message from A could be encrypted with Bpub, but B would have to release his pub key and sign the message to proof that only he can decrypt the message from A. But i want to keep it anonymous, that B doesn't have to show his identity when sending coins like in ZeroCoin